# Let $A = \{1\}, B = \{3\}$ Suppose $f = \{(1,3),(5,6)\}$ Is $f: A \rightarrow B$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> Let $A = \{1\}, B = \{3\}$
>
> Suppose $f = \{(1,3),(5,6)\}$ Is $f$ a function from $A$ to $B$?

The definition of the function, say $F$, that the book gives:

$$\tag 1 \forall a \in A \exists! b \in B ((a,b) \in F)$$

Then $F: A \rightarrow B$

Coming back to our example: although we have $(5,6) \in f$ and $5 \notin A$ and $6 \notin B$, but, if I get it correctly, main condition of the function is not violated, hence I believe that **yes**, $f$ is a function from $A$ to $B$.

I've tried to answer my own question, but I need your verification:  is $f$ a function from $A$ to $B$?

Comment: Think of a function as a machine that takes inputs from A and produces elements of B.

Comment: @Ripi2, so if I get you correctly, in the example I provided, $f$ *is* a function. Right?

Comment: You seem to have skipped the part of a function being a special kind of relation, a relation that satisfies the definition you give.  Yes, a function satisfies the definition you give, but first and foremost, *it is a relation* from $A$ to $B$, meaning a subset of $A\times B$.  $(5,6)$ is not an element of $A\times B$ so $f$ fails to be a relation from $A$ to $B$ and as such fails to be a function from $A$ to $B$.

Comment: @Nelver  JMoravitz has pointed right. I think this  comment explain better than the answers posted here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually a function $f$ is *from* $A$ *to* $B$, we have $$f\subseteq A\times B,$$
so I would say that $f$ is not $A\to B$.

If that's your only definition, then technically it meets it, but it's not standard.

Comment: It's worth noting that this statement that $F\subseteq A\times B$ along with the statement $\forall a\in A \exists! b\in B ((a,b)\in F)$ *is* the usual set theory definition of a function (i.e. to clarify that this added property actually completes the usual definition of a function)

Answer (score 1):

Ive never seen a definition of function $f:A\to B$ that allows $f\subset C\times D$ where $A$ is a *proper* subset of $C$.

Every definition I've ever seen would state $f:A\to B$ and $f\subset A\times B$ and in which case this is *definitely* not a function as $5\in A$ and $f \not \subset A\times B$.

However according to the definition you gave, it states nothing of the sort so indeed it satisfies all the requirements you gave.  For all $a\in A$ (that is if $a = 1$) there is a unique $b \in B$ ($3$).

So it is a function by *your* definition.

But your definition is lame.  Because $f\not \subset A\times B$ and it's just plain *weird* to allow for $(a,b)\in f$ where $a \not \in A$.

Answer (score -1):

The domain and range of $f$ are not $A$ and $B$ respectively, but instead are $\{1,5\}$ and $\{3,6\}$ respectively.

Comment: The extensional definition of  the function f does not tell us what is the range of f ( = the set of all possible Y-values). But it tells us that the range of f is a superset of the set {3,6}, in other words, taht { 3,6} is a subset of the range of f.